# Preserving NULL values in a Double Variable

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a vb.net application which imports from an Excel spreadsheet.

```
If rdr.HasRows Then
        Do While rdr.Read()
            If rdr.GetValue(0).Equals(System.DBNull.Value) Then
                Return Nothing
            Else
                Return rdr.GetValue(0)
            End If
        Loop
    Else
```

I was using string value to store the double values and when preparing the database statement I'd use this code:

```
If (LastDayAverage = Nothing) Then
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WF_LAST_DAY_TAG", System.DBNull.Value)
        Else
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WF_LAST_DAY_TAG", Convert.ToDecimal(LastDayAverage))
        End If
```

I now have some data with quite a few decimal places and the data was put into the string variable in scientific notation, so this seems to be the wrong approach.  It didn't seem right using the string variable to begin with.

If I use a double or decimal type variable, the blank excel values come across as 0.0.

How can I preserve the blank values?

---

Note: I have tried

Variable as Nullabe(Of Double)

But when passing the value to the SQL insert I get: "Nullable object must have a value."

---

Solution:

Fixed by changing the datatype of the parameter in the sub I was calling and then using Variable.HasValue to do the conditional DBNull insert.

Comment: Are there any values that are 0.0 that shouldn't be null?

Comment: Does that field in the DB allow nulls?

Comment: Yes, there are 0.0 and there are nulls.  That's the problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know which API you're using to do database inserts, but with many of them, including ADO.NET, the proper way to insert nulls is to use [DBNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value(v=VS.100).aspx).  So my recommendation is that you use `Nullable(Of Double)` in your VB code, but then when it comes time to do the insert, you'd substitute any null values with `DBNull.Value`.

Answer (score 3):

You need the question mark ? to let Double (or any value type) can store null (or Nothing). E.g.:

```
Dim num as Double? = Nothing
```

Note the ? mark.

To store in the db:

```
If num Is Nothing Then
  ... System.DBNull.Value ...
Else
  ... num ...
End If
```

or better:

```
If num.HasValue Then
  ... System.DBNull.Value ...
Else
  ... num.Value ...
End If
```

Comment: This way 0.0 is a value and num = Nothing is a null value that is not 0.0.

Comment: Note that you cannot assign only null (or Nothing) to be store in DB. Thats why .Net have System.DBNull.Value. You need to do the If Else to store either System.DBNull.Value or the correct value.

Comment: Using your syntax gives "Character Not Valid".  I'm using VS 2005.  Perhaps this is a newer .net framework syntax?

Comment: Both c# and VB.NET use the same "?" I just notice that Double? same as Nullable(Of Double) or Nullable<Double>

Comment: The ? symbol for Nullable types in VB is only valid for VB9 and higher.  It did not exist in VB8 (released with VS2005)

Answer (score 0):

I am posting an article [HERE](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/85-Why-NULL-Values-Should-Not-Be-Used-in-a-Database-Unless-Required.htm) while I keep looking for how to acheive a solution to your situation, but the article might have another solution which is to remove the null values, and add a default value. If I find anything else I will post it.

> When you set up a database (at least
>   in MS SQL Server) you can flag a field
>   as allowing NULL values and which
>   default values to take. If you look
>   through people's DB structures, you'll
>   see that a lot of people allow NULL
>   values in their database. This is a
>   very bad idea. I would recommend never
>   allowing NULL values unless the field
>   can logically have a NULL value (and
>   even this I find this only really
>   happens in DATE/TIME fields).
>
> NULL values cause several problems. For starters, NULL values
>   are not the same as data values. A
>   NULL value is basically an undefined
>   values. On the ColdFusion end, this is
>   not terrible as NULL values come
>   across as empty strings (for the most
>   part). But in SQL, NULL and empty
>   string are very different and act very
>   differently. Take the following data
>   table for example:
>
> ```
> id    name
> ---------------
> 1     Ben
> 2     Jim
> 3     Simon
> 4     <NULL>
> 5     <NULL>
> 6     Ye
> 7
> 8
> 9     Dave
> 10
> ```
>
> This table has some empty strings (id: 7, 8, 10) and some NULL values
>   (id: 4, 5). To see how these behave
>   differently, look at the following
>   query where we are trying to find the
>   number of fields that do not have
>   values:
>
> ```
>  Launch code in new window » Download code as text file »
>
>     * SELECT
>     * (
>     * SELECT
>     * COUNT( * )
>     * FROM
>     * test t
>     * WHERE
>     * LEN( t.name ) = 0
>     * ) AS len_count,
>     * (
>     * SELECT
>     * COUNT( * )
>     * FROM
>     * test t
>     * WHERE
>     * t.name IS NULL
>     * ) AS null_count,
>     * (
>     * SELECT
>     * COUNT( * )
>     * FROM
>     * test t
>     * WHERE
>     * t.name NOT LIKE '_%'
>     * ) AS like_count,
>     * (
>     * SELECT
>     * COUNT( * )
>     * FROM
>     * test t
>     * WHERE
>     * t.name IS NULL
>     * OR
>     * t.name NOT LIKE '_%'
>     * ) AS combo_count
>
> This returns the following record:
>
> LEN Count: 3
> NULL Count: 2
> LIKE Count: 3
> Combo Count: 5
> ```
>
> We were looking for 5 as records 4, 5, 7, 8, and 10 do not have values
>   in them. However, you can see that
>   only one attempt returned 5. This is
>   because while a NULL value does NOT
>   have a length, it is not a data type
>   that makes sense with length. How can
>   nothing have or not have a length?
>   It's like asking "What does that math
>   equation smell like?" You can't make
>   comparisons like that.
>
> So, allowing NULL values makes you work extra hard to get the kind of
>   data you are looking for. From a
>   related angle, allowing NULL values
>   reduces your convictions about the
>   data in your database. You can never
>   quite be sure if a value exists or
>   not. Does that make you feel safe and
>   comfortable when programming?
>
> Furthermore, while running LEN() on a NULL value doesn't act as you
>   might think it to, it also does NOT
>   throw an error. This will make
>   debugging your code even harder if you
>   do not understand the difference
>   between NULL values and data values.
>
> Bottom line: DO NOT ALLOW NULL VALUES unless absolutely necessary.
>   You will only be making things harder
>   for yourself.

Comment: This got me thinking a bit more about the situation and I'm consulting with the process owners.  Perhaps we can just leave the row out of the db, unless they need to know that a measurement was not taken for the day.

Comment: They do need to store the null value, or at least the fact that the value was not available.

Comment: @Sam Not a problem. I had discussed it with my co workers and in certain situations a null value can be useful, example: if a student doesn't take an exam they would have a null value and not a 0.0 as a score for the exam, if they had a 0.0 it would count as failing and not as not completing the exam, thus resulting in a inconsistency for their average.