# Nullable type with inline if cannot work together?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, nullable

Given the following code:

```
Dim widthStr As String = Nothing
```

This works - `width` is assigned `Nothing`:

```
Dim width As Nullable(Of Double)
If widthStr Is Nothing Then
  width = Nothing
Else
  width = CDbl(widthStr)
End If
```

But this does not - `width` becomes `0.0` (although it seems to be logically identical code):

```
Dim width As Nullable(Of Double) = If(widthStr Is Nothing, Nothing, CDbl(widthStr))
```

Why? Is there anything I can do to make it work?

Comment: did you try the same in C#? `double? width = widthStr != null ? Double.Parse(widthStr) : (double?)null;`

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633824/nullable-type-with-inline-if-cannot-work-together http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647558/preserving-null-values-in-a-double-variable

Comment: @HighCore - `null` in C# and `Nothing` in VB.Net are *not* equivalent. `Nothing` is, approximately, `default(T)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This all comes down to type analysis of expressions.

`Nothing` is a magical beast in VB.Net. It's approximately the same as `default(T)` in C#.

As such, when trying to determine the best type for the following:

```
If(widthStr Is Nothing, Nothing, CDbl(widthStr))
```

The third argument is of type `Double`. The second argument is convertible to `Double` (because `Nothing` can return the default value of value types). As such, the type of the return value of `If` is determined to be `Double`.

Only *after* that piece of type analysis has concluded is any attention paid to the type of the variable to which this expression is being assigned. And `Double` is assignable to `Double?` without any warnings.

---

There's no *clean* way to make your `If()` expression work how you expected. Because there's no equivalent to `null` in VB.Net. You'd need (at the least) to insert a `DirectCast` (or equivalent) on one side or another of the potential results of the `If` to force the type analysis to see `Double?` rather than `Double`.

Comment: +1, even though I don't think I completely understand your answer. Are you suggesting that such inline `If` is a generic function under the hood? And that's how VS works for inferring types for it?

Comment: @Neolisk - I've edited my question a few times since first posted - have you read the most recent version? `If` isn't a generic function. But `Nothing` is, as I've said, a magical beast. It's typeless (in and of itself) and so any other type information is used first.

Comment: Interesting, although I would expect type analysis to consider the type of the left side of equation. Anyway, thanks for such a thorough explanation.

Comment: @Neolisk - frequently, there *is* no left side (consider a `Dim` without a type, any subexpression, or use as a parameter to a function - it has to determine the type of the result of the expression before it can determine which overload to call)

Answer (score 12):

Further to Damien's answer, the clean way to do this is to *not* use `Nothing`, but `New Double?` instead:

```
Dim width As Double? = If(widthStr Is Nothing, New Double?, CDbl(widthStr))
```

And now that the type of  the `If` expression is correct, this could be reduced to:

```
Dim width = If(widthStr Is Nothing, New Double?, CDbl(widthStr))
```

Comment: +1. Thanks for a suggestion. I generally prefer not to use any of the special characters, for code clarity. So `Dim width As Nullable(Of Double) = If(widthStr Is Nothing, New Nullable(Of Double), CDbl(widthStr))` is more preferable.

Comment: I understand your preference to not use "special characters" (I wouldn't use any type characters for variables -- but I will for constants.) but in this case the IDE throws errors referring to the `?` form for `Nullable(Of )`.

Comment: No, just that when dealing with errors regarding code that uses `Nullable(Of Something)` the VB.NET compiler refers to `Something?`.