# Store Nothing in Nullable Double wtih if statement

Tags: vb.net

I just stumbled upon something really weird with nullable variables:

```
'Normal case 
Dim myNumber As Double? = Nothing
Dim hasValue As Boolean = myNumber.HasValue 'False as expected

'Weird case
Dim myNumber2 As Double? = If(True, Nothing, 42)
Dim hasValue2 As Boolean = myNumber2.HasValue 'True ?! (myNumber2 == 0)
```

Why does the if store a 0 instead of Nothing in my nullable Double ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nullable type with inline if cannot work together?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633824/nullable-type-with-inline-if-cannot-work-together)

Comment: Indeed. The workaround is `Dim myNumber2 As Double? = If(True, New Double?, 42)` (I really hate VB)

Comment: Or a good old if/else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `If(True, Nothing, 42)` is what is throwing you off.  For the `IF` statement, both results need to be the same type.  Since `Nothing` is not a type, VB automatically looks at the second result and casts the `Nothing` to a double which results in 0.0.

Comment: It's not that it's casting `Nothing` to `Double` it's that `Nothing` is not the same thing as `null`.  In VB, Nothing means use the default value for the type.  For `Double` which is a value type, the default is 0.0.  `Nothing` is closer to `default(T)` in C#.